# DataGrid is not firing KeyDown or KeyUp events

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I've attached an handler to the DataGridRowGroupHeader's KeyDown and KeyUp event, hoping to catch navigation when the user uses the arrow keys to select a **group** row, however I cannot get this event to fire. I can however get the MouseButtonUp event to fire for the DataGridRowGropHeader, but that's only half of the solution.

Comment: You could use something like Silverlight Spy to see what exactly is firing on those clicks.

Comment: According to Silverlight Spy, the DataGrid itself is the source of the only Key events when navigating within it. The question is how can the DataGrid be customized/derived such that it allows that event to make its way up to the DataGridRowGroupHeaders?

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use PreviewKeyDown event